# If a series is convergent is it possible to perform mathematical operations with its sum?

Tags: convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Suppose the series given by $$\left(\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_{k}|^{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ is convergent to a number S. Where $x_{k}\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|.|$ is the complex modulus. I want to know if it's possible to know if $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_{k}|^{2}}$ is a convergent series. I suppose it is a convergent series since S is a finite number and square a finite number is also finite, am I right?

Comment: But $S$ is not a series. It's the square root of the sum of a series.

Comment: I'm sorry, but  $S$ is not a series. It is what's between the parentheses that is a series.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will edit my question.

Comment: That's not a series.  And you question is self fulfilling.  If $(M)^{\frac 12} = L$ then *by definition* $L^2 = M$ and if $M = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = L^2$ and it converges... but we *ASSUMED* it converges in the *first* place when we claimed $(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k)^{\frac 12}$ had a meaningful value.  Your question is, literally (not judgementally), meaningless.

Comment: I like your answer. Now I see this question is somewhat logical tricky. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is not a series; it is the square root of a series. It turns out you are (in a roundabout way) correct though. $S^2$ is the square of the square root of a series, so it is a series itself.

To answer your general question, yes you can perform arithmetic with a convergent series. Like you said, you can treat it as a finite number.